# Forge Viewer v7: "getViewableUrn is not a function" - 7.33.1

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Not sure if this is a bug or an issue with script loading order. Using ES5 but in an ES6 capable browser. v6 works. Discovered this while upgrading to v7.

The line in "ChooseViewerItem" (a wrapper function to allow me to change viewables) - calls

`viewer.loadDocumentNode(document, viewable).then(onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);`

What am I missing?

```
Uncaught TypeError: avDocument.getViewableUrn is not a function
    loadDocumentNode Viewer3D.js:1738
    ChooseViewerItem a9dcd494-cecb-4391-a14e-834f7c7d8172:1280
    onDocumentLoadSuccess a9dcd494-cecb-4391-a14e-834f7c7d8172:1298
    onSuccess Document.js:174
    onSuccessWrapped Xhr.js:565
    onLoad Xhr.js:669
    _rawGet Xhr.js:707
    rawGet Xhr.js:573
    pendGo index.js:54
    go index.js:13
    rawGet Xhr.js:557
    getManifest Xhr.js:855
    doLoad Document.js:227
    load Document.js:231
    launchViewer a9dcd494-cecb-4391-a14e-834f7c7d8172:1272
    promise callback*Initializer envinit.js:629
    launchViewer a9dcd494-cecb-4391-a14e-834f7c7d8172:1261
    <anonymous> a9dcd494-cecb-4391-a14e-834f7c7d8172:922
    Angular 18
    jQuery 13
Viewer3D.js:1738
```

Comment: Could you share the contents of your `ChooseViewerItem` function? From the information you provided it's not clear how exactly you're loading the models.

Comment: @PetrBroz that was the issue. It was using the variable I saved the document reference in... "document"

Yeah I'll just walk away slowly in shame

Comment: No need for that :) Happens more frequently than you'd think. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Document](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Document) class is bundled with all the other basic classes in the *viewer3D.js* file so there should be no problems with loading order.

I'd suggest checking if the object you are passing into the `loadDocumentNode` method is actually an instance of `Document`.

Here's how models/viewables are typically loaded with Forge Viewer v7.*:

```js
async function loadModelViewable(viewer, urn, guid = null) {
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
        if (guid) {
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().findByGuid(guid));
        } else {
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry());
        }
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(code, message) {
        console.error(message);
    }
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
}
```

Comment: I was saving "doc" in a page-level variable. Named "document"

Two guesses why that didn't work, and the first doesn't count.